# Como colocar um link num background-image?

Tags: css, html5

Eu tenho uma div que tem essas características:

```
div#circulo{
 height:200px 
 width:200px
 background-image: url(minhaimagem.png);
 background-size:200px;
}
```

A imagem que se trata é de um circulo centralizado, com o fundo transparente. Então no meu html eu coloquei pra a div ser um link, deste modo:

```
<a href="proximapagina.html"><div id=circulo>...conteudo...</div></a>
```

Só que a área clicável ficou, como esperado, no quadrado inteiro da imagem. Tem como fazer com que a área clicável seja só o circulo interno??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Opção 1

Coloque um `border-radius` no link:

```
a{
   border-radius: 50%
}
```

Obs.: A área tracejada é a "área clicável" do *anchor*

### DEMO

```css
a div {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #09f;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
}
a{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px dashed #333;   
  padding: 4px;
  width: auto;
}
a.com {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Sem o border-radius no link</h2>
<a class="sem" href="proximapagina.html">
  <div id=circulo>...conteudo...</div>
</a>

<br><br>

<h2>Com o border-radius no link</h2>
<a class="com" href="proximapagina.html">
  <div id=circulo>...conteudo...</div>
</a>
```

#### Opção 2

Use um [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map):

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9e/Flag_of_Japan.svg/290px-Flag_of_Japan.svg.png" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map">
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="146,154,124,150,103,136,91,115,88,88,96,66,110,51,129,40,154,39,176,48,188,56,199,72,204,97,200,118,188,136,167,150,122" />
</map>
```

No caso acima criei um *shape* com as coordenadas correspondentes ao círculo presente na bandeira do Japão. Exite também a opção `shape="circle"`, mas isso você pode explorar mais a fundo.

É aplicados para imagens e, apesar da criação poder parecer complicada, existem algumas aplicações para isso, como o próprio Dreamweaver e sites como [este](http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/).

Comment: Poderia apenas um display: block; resolver?

Comment: @taiar, o display: inline-block; foi apenas com o objetivo de ajustar o tamanho do link ao seu conteudo, mas se o autor preferir, ele pode colocar um display: block, e setar o tamanho no próprio link, ao invés de no conteúdo, como [nesse exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/e26mcvv0/)

Comment: Olá, usei o border-radius como tu falou e funcionou, (em parte) porque agora tem algumas áreas da minha página que ficaram com tipo uma "área clicável" aleatória, sem dever estar ali. Como resolver?

Comment: @NicolasSchinestzki, você aplicou o estilo diretamente no seletor a `a`, se foi, deve aplicar a algo mais restrito, como uma classe, senão os estilos vão para todos os links. Senão foi isso, pode mais específico?

Comment: Eu acabei de ver que o erro era totalmente sem sentido.. Mas o border-radius funcionou mesmo! Obrigado